# How to prevent render image overwriting

Tags: rendering

I just overwritten my rendered image because I wanted to have in landscape and in portrait mode so when second render was done I was going to save it and I didn't changed default name of file so first image was overwritten. How do I prevent this from happening again? Is there an option to prevent me from saving until I changed a name (I know there is red color as warning when name already exist but it seems like that isn't enough for me.

Comment: Uncheck 'Overwrite' in the Render >Output  panel?.. I may have missed your point, though ..

Comment: @RobinBetts Well that seems to doesn't effect images saves since you do that manually not via output settings. It still let me overwrite image just like before.

Comment: I just now written over my texture with a render of the object I was texturing. Now I have to start over.